# Redux - Where to Store Default State?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Going through some Redux examples, we see sometimes the default state is defined by piece in Reducers.

`const scoreReducer = (score = 0, action)=>{return action.score}`

And other times we see it imported from a central file,

`import defaultState from './'
const scoreReducer = (score = defaultState.score, action)=>{return action.score}`

Is there a strong reason why one should go with either solution?

Comment: It could depend on the size or complexity of the default state. If you've got some complex json as default state it could look really ugly inline. So you put it in a different file for cleanness.

Comment: When your state becomes complex enough that you've broken reducers out to reflect branches of the state, you may want to have the initial state of each reducer reflect just that one branch.  It's easier and cleaner to deal with that way.